# How to get Ajax to use CSS form validation before submitting

Tags: css, ajax, forms, validation

What would be the best way to get this to use CSS form validation before submitting?  Now it will submit no matter what.

```
$('#contact_submit_btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // This will prevent page refresh
    $.ajax({
        url: 'contact_form.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $("#contact_form_id").serialize(),
        success: function(msg) {
            alert('Email Sent');
            //contact_submit();
        }               
    });
});
```

I guess a simple if/else I just don't know what to check for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do if/else statements, or you can use several different libraries that are out there. For instance, jquery has a form validation plugin that you can use. The code in this case would look something like:

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  if ( $( "input:first" ).val() === "correct" ) {
     $.ajax({
        url: 'contact_form.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $("#contact_form_id").serialize(),
        success: function(msg) {
            alert('Email Sent');
            //contact_submit();
        }               
    });
  }

  $( "span" ).text( "Not valid!" ).show().fadeOut( 1000 );
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: No problem. Happy coding.